# Cartthrob DB error

Tags: cartthrob

When trying to login I get the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1142
INSERT command denied to user 'ID121723_herbaco'@'79.174.131.25' for table 'exp_security_hashes'
INSERT INTO `exp_security_hashes` (`date`, `hash`, `session_id`) VALUES (1440241989,'d89e683a2775a41b7d75cb9ef4de58e06d431d5c',0)
Filename: core/EE_Security.php
Line Number: 237
```

Anyone have any idea? Site uses Cartthrob but I have no idea if that's the culprit. Any insight much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to CartThrob, because that table is part of the EE default tables. I've seen this before when exp_security_hashes is corrupted. Can you (or your host) try repairing it?

Comment: Cheers Matt. While I have your attention, this particular DB's exp_cartthrob_cart table is already 200MB large... is it safe to delete it (or part of it)?

Comment: You should be ok deleting the rows from the table (don't delete the table itself)-- just be aware that if someone has something in their cart but hasn't checked out yet, deleting the row will clear their cart.

Comment: cheers mate, appreciate it!